# How "Hello World" gets printed? - a complete life cycle

Tags: java, architecture, compiler-construction, operating-system

I took compiler, operating system, computer architecture course in graduate school. But I  want to see those concepts in a simple but real example (not too theoretical). HelloWorld is a good choice for simple example.

Not only the life cycle of this little program is interesting, but also knowing how JVM, OS and Architecture works can help us to become a better programmer.

In short, my question is: do I describe the steps correctly and completely?

In detail, I need your help with the following:

1. Point out any part that I am wrong
2. I'm sure I miss a lot of valuable points, so please add any point that makes sense in the life cycle.

What I want to know is how HelloWorld goes through each layer, and then come back from it. Assume this program runs on an  **Intel** CPU with **Ubuntu**.

**I will keep this post updated by combining good answers until one answer is finally accepted.**

The following is THE HelloWorld program that everybody knows.

[image]

It is compiled to bytecode like the following.

[image]

The bytecode is not readable, but we can use `javap -classpath . -c HelloWorld` to see mnemonics like the following.

[image]

Then it gets loaded, linked and initialized in JVM.

[image]

Since it has only one thread, let's assume it is the the left thread in the following JVM run-time data area.

[image]

JVM threads are user-level threads, so it will be mapped to kernel. In Ubuntu, it is one-to-one mapping like the following:

[image]

Now JVM makes the x86 instructions? (update)

What is operating system's role for this particular program?

What is next in Architecture?

Fetch instruction, decode, execute, memory access, write back in 5-steps MIPS.

[image]

References:

1. [OS basics](http://www.pling.org.uk/cs/ops.html)
2. [Diagrams](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/04/how-hello-world-gets-printed-a-complete-life-cycle/)

This could be an extremely difficult question. Unlike questions of how to use a certain API, this requires understanding of almost everything.

Comment: The JVM makes x86 instructions.

Comment: Cool, but I would say its home is somewhere else.

Comment: I believe we have a wiki or something somewhere around here. If someone with enough rep comes by, they have the ability to move it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Java virtual machine (JVM) is a virtual machine that can execute Java bytecode. It is the code execution component of the Java platform.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine

Image courtesy of wikipedia:

[image]